# Non-editable text paste target

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Users need to be able to paste the contents of an Excel spreadsheet into a grid in my flex application.

I have implemented this using a `TextArea` with a `change` event handler that parses the text the the user pastes - splitting it up by newlines and tabs - and adding it to the `ArrayCollection` that is bound to the grid.

However, it makes no sense for users to be able to manually enter text into the `TextArea`. How can I prevent them from doing so?

Or: would it make more sense to create my own component that implements `IFocusManagerComponent`?

Comment: It would be best if you had a `Validator` which shows an error if the text in the TextArea is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]
A bit messy, please cleanup the code before use:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        protected function keyDownEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            switch(e.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.V: 
                    if (e.ctrlKey)
                    {
                        ta.text += "Some dummy " + "\n" +
                            "text pasted in this text area";
                        ta.text += "\n[Keyboard Used to paste]";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        protected function onCreationComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            ta.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEvent);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label text="Press CTRL[V] to see the action"/>
<s:TextArea id="ta"/>
```